# Extracting text information using rapidminer

Tags: text, full-text-search, text-processing, rapidminer

I have a list of text data from which I want to extract certain portions.  I am currently using a regular expression to extract the data I want, but it's starting to get very complicated because each record is slightly different.  Is there a way to use Rapidminer to "learn" a regular expression based on some typical examples?

For example, for each of the following records I want to extract the text `24` and `18` into two new attributes:

```
word 24 on line 18
Wrd 24 of Ln 18
Line 18, Word 24
Word 24 comes after word 22 on line 18 (not line 19)
```

I have watched all the text processing videos, but none of them show how to do this sort of thing, and I don't really know where to start.  Can anyone suggest a way of doing this other than manually creating regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

The [TXR language](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) has a straightforward way to express pattern matching variants without cryptic regular expressions:

Here is your data file:

```
$ cat 13249396.dat 
word 24 on line 18
Wrd 24 of Ln 18
Line 18, Word 24
Word 24 comes after word 22 on line 18 (not line 19)
```

Here is the txr script:

```
@(collect)
@  (some)
word @wd on line @ln
@  (or)
Wrd @wd of Ln @ln
@  (or)
Line @ln, Word @wd
@  (or)
Word @wd comes after word @nil on line @ln (@(skip)
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@wd:@ln
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Test run:

```
$ txr 13249396.txr 13249396.dat
24:18
24:18
24:18
24:18
```

The script was developed by taking the cases from the sample file and replacing a few things by bits of special syntax.